# Update with Where, Order by and Limit does not work

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am using SQLite 3.

When I input the following query

```
UPDATE MyTable Set Flag = 1 WHERE ID = 5 Order By OrderID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I will always get an error:

> near Order By, syntax error

I cannot figure out what is the problem with my query

Comment: I don't know about sqlite, but I guess limit 1 can't be used in update. Regardless, what is the logic here?? You have an N amount of rows with OrderID=5 and you want only one of them, ARBITRARILY, to get a flag=1?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, yes, There will be multiple records with ID = 5, I will sort all of them by OrderID and only the one with the largest OrderID will be updated.

Comment: Show output of `PRAGMA compile_options;`

Comment: @alancc I've posted my answer based on your comments under MajidVahidkhoo answer, hope that helps. You should update your initial question with what you're writing in comments, though - for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROWID`:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Flag = 1 
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 5 
                ORDER BY OrderID DESC LIMIT 1);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=40e844a0c69242b02ff3a5acccbc3ace)**

or `(ID,OrderID)` tuple:

```
UPDATE  MyTable 
SET Flag = 1 
WHERE (ID, ORDERID) IN (SELECT  ID, ORDERID FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 5 
                        ORDER BY OrderID DESC LIMIT 1);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=34b7d51c0b3399b3062f1e2c0c0c97b7)**

---

And if you need to do it in bulk for every ID(SQLite 3.25.0):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OrderID DESC) AS rn FROM tab
)
UPDATE tab
SET Flag = 1
WHERE (ID, OrderID) IN (
       SELECT ID, OrderID
       FROM cte
       WHERE rn = 1
      );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I belive using ROWID is more faster than using (ID, OrderID) pair. So I set your solution as the answer and give 50 reputation to you.

Answer (score 3):

To use LIMIT and ORDER BY in an UPDATE or DELETE statement, you have to do two things:

- Build a custom version of the sqlite3.c amalgamation from source, configuring it with the `--enable-update-limit` option.
- Compile that custom sqlite3.c into your project with [SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) defined to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. That seems a little complex.

Comment: Is there a workaround that can support ORDER BY and LIMIT in UPDATE or DELETE without having to recompile sqlite3.c?

Comment: **[Working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=545d29c1876b84fdf389e203305ffbcb)**

Answer (score 2):

"Order By OrderID DESC LIMIT 1" is for selecting top one ordered result
so you should use it in select query.
you should do a subquery where you first get the id and then update it:

```
UPDATE  MyTable 
SET Flag = 1 
WHERE (ID,OrderID) IN (SELECT ID,OrderID
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ID = 5 
ORDER BY OrderID DESC LIMIT 1);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=8053dfb787a6b31541165d846e7f7575)

Comment: Your answer is the best one. The only problem is that there may be multiple rows with the same ID but different OrderID. That is the reason why I need to find out the row with the specific ID as well as the maximum OrderID and update it. With ID and Order ID, I can identify an unique row. With ID only, I may get multiple rows while only one with the maximum OrderID is the one I want to update.

Comment: I write a query: UPDATE MyTable SET Flag = 1 WHERE (ID = 5) AND (OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 5 Order by OrderID DESC LIMIT 1)); Is it correct?

Comment: This answer does not make any sense because it is equivalent of `UPDATE MyTable SET Flag=1 WHERE ID = 5` -- every row with ID = 5 will be updated not the one with highest OrderID

Comment: **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=401793a332a3dc1b7cccd99c7ac5e263)** and please compare with approach that uses ROWID/tuple - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558111/5070879

Comment: @alancc, sorry, I forgot to select OrderId, Now, its work.

Answer (score 1):

Order By statement will not work in update query.
You have to use alternate way

```
UPDATE MyTable Set Flag = 1 WHERE ID = 5 
and OrderId = (select max(OrderId) from MyTable where Id = 5);
```

If you have used the query like above it will work.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

Below I'm presenting two solutions to solve the issue and perform a proper `UPDATE`. At the end of each solution there's a live example on sample data included.

- **First** does not require you to input any `id` and works for the entire table by picking the latest `orderid` for each `id` and changing it's `flag` to `1`
- **Second** requires you to input an `id` and works only for updating one `id` on the run

I'd personally go with **first** solution, but I am not sure about your requirement, thus posting two possibilities.

### First solution - update entire table

**Explanation** here, for code scroll down.

For this we will use [Row Value](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) construction `(id, orderid)` just like for the second solution.
It will find the latest row based on `orderid` and update only that row for given `(id, orderid)` pair. More on that is included in Explanation of second solution.

We will also need to simulate `row_number` function to assign each row ranking numbers, to find out which row has the latest `orderid` for every `id` and mark then as `1` to be able to pull only those for update. This will allow us to update multiple rows for different ids in one statement. SQLite will have this functionality [built in version 3.2.5](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html) but for now, we will work with a subquery.

To generate row numbers we will use this:

```
select 
  *, 
  (select count(*) from mytable m1 where m1.id = m2.id and m1.orderid >= m2.orderid) as rn
from mytable m2
```

Then we just need to filter the output on `rn = 1` and we have what we need.

That said, the whole `UPDATE` statement will look like:

**Code**

```
update mytable
set flag = 1
where (id,orderid) in (
  select id, orderid
  from (
    select *, (select count(*) from mytable m1 where m1.id = m2.id and m1.orderid >= m2.orderid) as rn
    from mytable m2
    ) m
  where 
    m.rn = 1
    and m.id = mytable.id
  );
```

**Live DEMO**

Here's **[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mcA4RMceQTewob9xbcErD8/0)** to see this solution live on sample data.

---

### Second solution - update only one ID

If you know your `ID` to be updated and want to run `UPDATE` statement for only one id, then this will work:

**Code**

```
update mytable
set flag = 1
where (id,orderid) in (
  select id, orderid
  from mytable
  where id = 5
  order by orderid desc
  limit 1
  );
```

**Explanation**

`(id, orderid)` is a construction called [**Row Value**](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) for which SQLite compares scalar values from left to right.

Example taken from documentation:

```
SELECT (1,2,3) = (1,2,3) -- outputs: 1
```

**Live DEMO**

Here's **[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8WwmHYUi91RmGf6nsPQ5G/0)** to see this solution live on sample data.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL**

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Flag = 1
WHERE ID = 5
AND OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE ID = 5
                ORDER BY OrderID DESC
                LIMIT 1);
```

**Demo**

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6d596/2